# Odoo filter Inventory Overview by receipt

Tags: odoo, erp, inventory, odoo-15

Is it possible to filter the inventory overview page by a field on a `stock.picking` object? For example, I want to create a search option at the top of the page like `"Search receipt references for: \<User entered text\>"`

I'm using Odoo version 15. Thanks!

[image]

I've tried doing something like `<field name="stock_picking_ids" string="receipts" domain="[('reference', 'ilike', self)]" />`

This seems to be doing some type of filter, because it will filter for no results if I enter some text that matches nothing like `"adfafdasfsfdf"`, but none of the counts are changing if I enter any text that would match at least one record like `"21"`.